# MacBook Primary screen disabled after connected to external screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook

I am having MacBook Pro Mid 2012 and I was connecting it to an external display but accidentally I miss placed something in the **Display>Arrangement** section

[image]

As in the image I click on the white bar from the small screen then drag and drop it to a large screen.

And after that, my MacBook is giving me a display like this [image]

And this display shows me nothing and no display is shown on the external screen either, after unplugging the monitor everything goes to normal,

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to 'fix'? That's normal behaviour if you set your external screen to be primary, whilst also using "displays have separate spaces'.

Comment: can I reverse everything? because my secondary screen is not been detected, only the laptop screen becomes disabled while the plugin

Comment: You should be able to drag the bar back to your internal screen, when the other is connected.

Comment: If my external screen is not working, then is there any other way to reverse things?

Comment: It should drop back to the remaining screen. If not, have you rebooted?

Comment: what happens if you tick "mirror displays"? Does you macbook screen work in that scenario?